# How do I uninstall and reinstall Node on macOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

```
nicolasrulli@Nicolas-Rullis-MacBook-Pro / % brew install node 
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 55 formulae.

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/node/manifests/18.2.0
Already downloaded: /Users/nicolasrulli/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d3348030d8404d01cc32c085f75250b04ad35d8c17b9c7e5cbb2d1bc3617e697--node-18.2.0.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/node/blobs/sha256:bc6d55e53035991aaa6d1917f396d2f0cd9e0281e80d1ba79e99211c5e82a
Already downloaded: /Users/nicolasrulli/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/5daf56787ecaf72b3065acd64fff548c38ec43c7572d18b603bc33da86aa53a2--node--18.2.0.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node--18.2.0.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
/usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link node
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall node
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/18.2.0: 1,930 files, 49.2MB
==> Running `brew cleanup node`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
nicolasrulli@Nicolas-Rullis-MacBook-Pro / % brew link node 
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/18.2.0... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
/usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.
nicolasrulli@Nicolas-Rullis-MacBook-Pro / % brew postinstall node
==> Postinstalling node
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall node
nicolasrulli@Nicolas-Rullis-MacBook-Pro / %
```

I ran `brew uninstall --force node` and that 'worked'. I then ran `brew cleanup` and it worked also. Next was `brew install node`. This started to run but then gave errors saying the link command couldn't run. Any advice?

Comment: _"/usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable"_. That seems rather self-explanatory? Make have to make it writable for the user you're running `brew` with.

Answer (score 1):

**Node.js uninstall command this**

`brew uninstall --force node`

**Node.js install**

Then you can download the version you want by entering `https://nodejs.dev/download`. The advice I can give you is to install nvm. In this way, you can use more versions.

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: Where should I run 'brew uninstall --force node' ? from my root directory?

Comment: No,You will write in the directory where node.js is installed.